# JsonArray to Kotlin data class using Retrofit and GsonConverterFactory(Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY)

Tags: android, json, kotlin, gson, retrofit2

I'm trying to load quotesJson file from github(https://github.com/JamesFT/Database-Quotes-JSON/blob/master/quotes.json). I'm new to retrofit and all of this, so I just tried following and understanding a tutorial(https://android.jlelse.eu/android-networking-in-2019-retrofit-with-kotlins-coroutines-aefe82c4d777) . Incredibly sorry if this is stupid or really easy. I'm still struggling with this. If i can get a short explanation of why it's done some other way I'd appreciate it!

I've looked at documentation for Retrofit, searched all of the similar overflow questions. The problem is, if I try to change 
`fun getQuotes(): Deferred<Response<QuoteResponse>>`
to 
`fun getQuotes(): Deferred<ResponseList<Quotes>>` 
I get an error in 
`val quoteResponse = safeApiCall(...`

```
    private val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
        .build()

    fun retrofit() : Retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .baseUrl("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JamesFT/Database-Quotes-JSON/master/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .addCallAdapterFactory(CoroutineCallAdapterFactory())
        .build()


    val quoteApi : QuoteApi = retrofit().create(QuoteApi::class.java)

}
```

model

```
   val quoteAuthor : String,
   val quoteText : String
)

// Data Model for the Response returned from the Api
data class QuoteResponse(
    val results : List<Quote>
)

//A retrofit Network Interface for the Api
interface QuoteApi{
    @GET("quotes.json")
    fun getQuotes(): Deferred<Response<QuoteResponse>>
    // fun getQuotes(): Deferred<Response<QuoteResponse>>
}
```

```
val quoteResponse = safeApiCall(
            call = {api.getQuotes().await()}, // i get the error here if i change something myself
            errorMessage = "Error Fetching Popular Movies"
        )

        return quoteResponse?.results?.toMutableList()

    }
```

```
suspend fun <T : Any> safeApiCall(call: suspend () -> Response<T>, errorMessage: String): T? {

        val result : Result<T> = safeApiResult(call,errorMessage)
        var data : T? = null

        when(result) {
            is Result.Success ->
                data = result.data
            is Result.Error -> {
                Log.d("1.DataRepository", "$errorMessage & Exception - ${result.exception}")
            }
        }


        return data

    }
```

````
    Process: com.example.quoteappmvvm, PID: 7373
    com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $
...

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginObject(JsonReader.java:385)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:215)```
````

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem you are facing is because the response is an array but you are trying to handle it as an object.

This is how your QuoteApi should look like

```
interface QuoteApi{
    @GET("quotes.json")
    fun getQuotes(): Deferred<Response<List<Quote>>>
}
```

Explanation:
To explain it a little better for you - your current expected response is

```
data class QuoteResponse(
    val results : List<Quote>
)
```

and Retrofit and Gson expect that your JSON response looks like

```
{
  "results": [...here would be your Qoute objects...]
}
```

when actually the response is only an array

```
[...here are Quote objects...]
```

.